# initialRegion.longitudeDelta` is marked as required in `MapView`, but its value is `undefined`

Tags: react-native

I want to get the current location but it render the component and show the map on it but location pointer is not available im showing the code i can understand what is the problem i have apply alot of different ways but failed.
Please have a look on this code why longitudeDelta is give me undefined now i apply hard coded values on it
    const latitudeDelta = 0.0922;
    const longitudeDelta = 0.1;

```
 watchID  = null
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            avatarSource: null,

            initialPosition:{
                latitude: 24.946218,
                longitude: 67.005615,
                latitudeDelta: latitudeDelta ,
                longitudeDelta:longitudeDelta
            },
            markerPosition:{
                    latitude:longitudeDelta,
                    longitude:latitudeDelta
            }
        }
    }



    componentDidMount(){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
            var lat = parseFloat(position.coords.latitude);
            var long = parseFloat(position.coords.longitude);

            var initialRegion = {
                latitude : lat,
                longitude: long,
                latitudeDelta: latitudeDelta,
                longitude: longitudeDelta
            }

            this.setState({initialPosition: initialRegion});
            this.setState({markerPosition:initialRegion})
        },
         (err) => alert(JSON.stringify(err)),
         {enableHighAccuracy:true, timeout:2000})

         this.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((positions) =>{
             var lat = parseFloat(positions.coords.latitude);
             var long = parseFloat(positions.coords.longitude);
             var initialRegions = {
                latitude : lat,
                longitude: long,
                latitudeDelta: latitudeDelta,
                longitude: longitudeDelta
            }
            this.setState({initialPosition: initialRegions});
            this.setState({markerPosition:initialRegions});
         })
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
        navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.watchID)
    }


<MapView style={{ height: 200 }}                                    initialRegion={this.state.initialPosition}
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var initialRegion = {
  latitude : lat,
  longitude: long,
  latitudeDelta: latitudeDelta,
  longitude: longitudeDelta
}
```

in the above code, you are assigning `longitudeDelta` to `longitude` instead of `longitudeDelta`. Correct it as below.

```
var initialRegion = {
  latitude : lat,
  longitude: long,
  latitudeDelta: latitudeDelta,
  longitudeDelta: longitudeDelta
}
```

But there is another issue in your code. `lat` and `long` are defined above. But you haven't defined `latitudeDelta` and `longitudeDelta`in your code.

Only one of either `latitudeDelta` or `longitudeDelta` is ever used for calculating the size of the map. So there is no big issue with hardcoding those two.

Comment: @RafaeKhatri If this answer was helpful, please accept the answer.

Comment: Buddy if this answer helped you, why don't you accept it? @RafaeKhatri

Comment: sorry i have used first time stackoverflow can you please help me?

Comment: @RafeeKhatri click on the up arrow(bottom left side of the answer. The circle with arrow mark)